# Render Image to XLS Report Using DynamicReports API

Tags: java, jasper-reports, dynamic-reports

I want to render image from a folder and display in Excel report.

Following codes used to render.

```
String headerImagePath = "/file/fileName.jpg"
BufferedImage img = null;

try {
    img = ImageIO.read(new File(headerImagePath)); 

}  catch (IOException e)  {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
JasperReportBuilder report = report();
report.title(cmp.image(img));
```

But image is not showing in excel sheet.

Any other option to render an image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it.!

You need pass the image file name as a parameter.

```
     parameters.put("header", headerImagePath);
```

Add the above parameters & it's `Class` to Jasper Report.

```
     report.addParameter("header", String.class);
```

You can add the image to report as follows

```
     report.title(cmp.image(exp.jasperSyntax("($P{header})",String.class)).setDimension(50, 130));
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the image path is correct?

You can check that easily by running:

```
System.out.println(new File(headerImagePath).exists());
```

If this code outputs `false` then you need to correct the path.

Comment: Yes. Image File exists.